# How to minify JS or CSS on the fly

Tags: php, javascript, css, optimization, minify

How to minify JS and CSS on the fly / runtime, so that I can keep the original code structure in my servers if its minified on the runtime / fly.

Comment: Why don't you keep the two versions? And use Minified in production and full in development?

Comment: It can sometimes make sense to want a way to minify on the fly.  For example I'm looking for code that I can insert into my existing cache system, so I just need a simple script to minify a string of CSS/JS, and my own code will take care of the caching.

Answer (score 24):

After a lot of searching and sites optimizations i really recommend to use this script for CSS files:

```
<style>
<?php
     $cssFiles = array(
      "style.css",
      "style2.css"
    );

    $buffer = "";
    foreach ($cssFiles as $cssFile) {
      $buffer .= file_get_contents($cssFile);
    }
    $buffer = preg_replace('!/\*[^*]*\*+([^/][^*]*\*+)*/!', '', $buffer);
    $buffer = str_replace(': ', ':', $buffer);
    $buffer = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n", "\t", '  ', '    ', '    '), '', $buffer);
    echo($buffer);
?>
</style>
```

It compress all css files into one and past it into html, reducing the number of additional requests to zero. You can also make your own compressed.css file if you prefer this than pasting styles into html.

Comment: its great if you could add how to save to compressed.css and load that! if i have do it i will update

Comment: While pasting the CSS into the HTML indeed reduces the amount of requests (with 1), it also prevents the CSS from being cached. A good caching meganism reduces both the number of requests and the size of the HTML documents.

Comment: Which is why you should always measure what's changing. If you're inlining your critical path css good chance you'll see a reduction in perceived latency, even though it's not cached, especially on mobile.

Comment: You can save minified CSS in localstorage as a cache literal, then use AJAX/Fetch HEAD request to check if the CSS file has been updated. If not, do not download the file and just load the CSS from the Storage.

Comment: This may cause render blocking. You should only provide main css in styles and other in link tag that should be loaded async after document render.

Answer (score 8):

I think your question should actually be: How can I reliably and repeatably update my live servers? What you need is an automatic deployment script. [Personally](http://andrewwilkinson.wordpress.com/2010/06/16/using-fabric-for-deployment/) I prefer [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.0.0/index.html), but there are other tools are available.

An automatic deployment script will allow you to run a single command which will go to live servers and update the source code, run any deployment steps (such as minifying javascript) and restart the webserver.

You really don't want to be minifying javascript or css files on the fly, you should do that once at deployment and then have a variable in your code that specifies whether this is a live deployment or not. If the variable is true then your links to the files should be links to the minimized version, if it's false then they should be to the normal versions.

There are a number of programs which perform minimization, one that hasn't been mentioned yet is [JSMin](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/jsmin.html).

Comment: This does not answer the question nor give a good solution.

Answer (score 6):

If your goal is to make your JavaScript slightly less readable, and do this at runtime, you could keep it very, very, simple. With just three lines of code you can get a long way toward total minification within a few milliseconds.

```
// make it into one long line
$code = str_replace(array("\n","\r"),'',$code);
// replace all multiple spaces by one space
$code = preg_replace('!\s+!',' ',$code);
// replace some unneeded spaces, modify as needed
$code = str_replace(array(' {',' }','{ ','; '),array('{','}','{',';'),$code);
```

This does not do any syntax checking whatsoever. Code can become invalid after using this. Check the end of the lines in your JS, is a ';' missing somewhere?

Comment: I've just tested this version and it generates JS error if there's a simple comment (//) in the original JS. As no line breaks here, check my comment for visualization at http://imgur.com/a/TzM30

Comment: No semantics awareness, limited minification techniques, lack of error handling, not extensible or maintainable, performance weakness. There are too many issues here. It's not a surprise that you've encountered errors while doing this. Not recommended at all!

Answer (score 4):

[HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) comes with a handy build script that compresses JS, CSS, images and much more. Check it out!

As explained in the other answers, “real” on-the-fly minification (dynamically compress a file every time it’s requested) wouldn’t be a very good idea.

Comment: When minified on the fly, just cache it in the file. If any source file timestamp changes - minify and cache it again on the fly. Worked for years in all my projects.

Answer (score 2):

If I may speak so freely;

Minifying a JS/CSS file would have as goal that it parses more quickly ( and also use up less disk space). By minifying it at runtime, that benefit would be completely lost.

Perhaps I am mistaken in your final goal, but this is what comes to my mind at first.

**Edit**: post by @Ant clarified it for me.

Comment: The runtime  minified file is cached, obviously. Even then, in good systems, it's minified at website start. When you have 258 properly refactored and architected JS files for your extremely larger Angular application, this is required. It must be runtime for debugging. Debug=true (depending on your system), might show you the true files and allow stepping.

Comment: This is not an answer. Place your comments in the question itself

Answer (score 2):

[Assetic](https://github.com/kriswallsmith/assetic) is a nice project that helps in organizing resources such as CSS and Javascript including minification. See [here](http://www.slideshare.net/kriswallsmith/introducing-assetic-asset-management-for-php-53) for an introduction.

Generally runtime minification should always be combined with solid caching on the server side and the usage of client and proxy caches along the way to the browser.

Answer (score 2):

If you have full control of your Apache / Ngnix configuration, a great option (in general) would be to enable the [PageSpeed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/) module, in your case with

- js-minify filter https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/filter-js-minify
- css-rewrite filter https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/filter-css-rewrite

Comment: I tried pagespeed and it sometimes compresses, sometimes not, others give a 404... I gave up with this solution

Answer (score -1):

You need to `system();` this

$ java -jar yuicompressor-x.y.z.jar

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/

Comment: Link provided is brocken and does not answer question

Answer (score -2):

Thats is exactly what **[WebUtilities](http://code.google.com/p/webutilities/)** (for J2EE) does. Here is the link.

> http://code.google.com/p/webutilities/

It does the minification and merging on the fly. It also has caching to avoid reruning the minification or reprocessing of a resource if resource not modified. It also helps with following optimizations.

- Serve multiple JS or CSS files in one request
- Add Expires header for JS, CSS and Image files to be cached by browser
- Minify JS, CSS files on the fly
- Minify Inline CSS and JS code blocks
- Add Character Encoding to your response
- Server compressed contents (gzip/compress/deflate)
- Cache responses to speed loading by avoiding reprocessing

Please have a look in case you find it interesting.

Comment: Anything like this for PHP-based server?

Comment: Question is clearly tagged as PHP... not java

Answer (score -2):

I am doubtful that this minification craze really makes that big of a difference if the JS is sent with zlib compression.

First, white space compresses extremely well, so the reduced filesize that results from minification is probably only a major issue with large libraries such as jQuery (which probably should be served from a CDN unless you need a hacked version).

Seconfly, JS is usually cached by the client so unless you use a lot of different scripts on different pages, most page loads it is not going to make a difference.

The problems with minification and why I do not do it (except with things like jQuery):
A) It strips out comments, so unless you re-add them, things like copyright notices are lost. This could result in a license violation, since even many OSS licenses require the copyright be intact.

B) When there is a problem, it is nice to see the actual code the server is serving just in case it happens to be different than your working copy. Minified code does not do well in that respect.

My personal opinion - zlib compress on the fly, yes. minify - only for really large files.

Performance parsing the JS into the interpreter - maybe if the browser is running on an Apple Performa with 32MB of RAM. I do not buy that it makes a real world difference with most scripts. Pages that are slow are usually slow because of too much inefficient code running at same time or are making too many requests to overloaded servers. (IE do you really need to check availability of username as I type each letter? Can't you check when I change to a different field or when I click submit ??? ;)

Comment: A. - is not true. Usually you can configure minifier to keep copyright comments. For example, see uglify documentation.

Comment: I disagree. When pages load they stop loading files if the file being loaded is a script (unless the async attribute is in use). If you open DevTools when a slow page is loading, you'll see that it is hanging because a script isn't being downloaded quickly. Cutting the script down to size helps somewhat.

Comment: As people like to say, you were on the "wrong side of history". Minification (a runtime process-- with the ability to enter "debug" modehas proven to be required for even the most small applications. With most AngularJS applications having dozens or hundreds of JS files, you have to combine/minify. This debate has been over for years. You should update your rant to reflect this.

Comment: Wow the date on my post is 2011. I do minify now, I keep them un-minified on the server but minify on the fly when served. It is sometimes funny to look back at old opinions on a topic.

Comment: @AliceWonder don't you wish you could go back 4 years in time and punch your younger self in the face? `:D` *(PS: just kidding)*